# R-Is there a way to combine list with variable number of rows to a dataframe

Tags: r

If there is a list of unequal number of row vectors(all the vectors have 3 columns) like below:

```
>typicalList

[[1]]
   col1          col2             col3
1   12            10              ABC
2   54            87              DEF

[[2]]
   col1          col2             col3
1    64            9             GHI
2    59            6             JKL
3    43            4             PST
```

Is it possible to have a dataframe from the above list with a new column called `newColumn` that looks like below:

```
newColumn col1     col2       col3
1          12        10       ABC
1          54        87       DEF
2          64        9        GHI
2          59        6        JKL
2          43        4        PST
```

Used `ldply(typicallist,rbind)` but that splits all the rows belonging to a vector in the original list giving 5 independent records in the dataframe. Is it possible to have the dataframe like above that suggests (through `newColumn`) field that first two records are derived from the first vector of the list and the remaining three from the second? Is there any better way to realize this in R?

Data

```
typicalList <- list(structure(list(col1 = c(12L, 54L), col2 = c(10L, 87L), col3 = c("ABC", 
"DEF")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2")), structure(list(col1 = c(64L, 59L, 43L), col2 = c(9L, 6L, 
4L), col3 = c("GHI", "JKL", "PST")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Comment: `do.call('rbind', Map(function(x, y) {x$newColumn <- y; x}, typicalList, seq(typicalList)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` with the `idcol` argument

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(typicalList, idcol = "newColumn")
#   newColumn col1 col2 col3
#1:         1   12   10  ABC
#2:         1   54   87  DEF
#3:         2   64    9  GHI
#4:         2   59    6  JKL
#5:         2   43    4  PST
```

---

Or use `bind_rows` with `.id` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(typicalList, .id = "newColumn")
#  newColumn col1 col2 col3
#1         1   12   10  ABC
#2         1   54   87  DEF
#3         2   64    9  GHI
#4         2   59    6  JKL
#5         2   43    4  PST
```